# Google Store locator Store Phone and Store Web not visible

Tags: google-maps

I am using [Google Store locator](https://www.drupal.org/project/google_store_locator) module for my Drupal 7 [website](http://litebook.eu/store_locator).

I have used version 7.x-1.1. But when I test my page the *Phone number* and *website* are not visible on the frontend?

If you can see there `http://litebook.eu/store-locator/json` in the browser you can see the data is added (*store phone* and *store web*).

Why are those fields not visible on the frontend?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is a patch you can apply that should fix your issue.

Check out the thread here https://www.drupal.org/node/2383773 and the related thread here https://www.drupal.org/node/2528458

This one https://www.drupal.org/node/2528458#comment-10125006 will take you straight to grabbing the patch, the top two will give you the context of what happened.